# Name clash between scope function and instance method

Tags: kotlin

I have the following interface, and code which uses that interface

```kotlin
interface Degenerate {
  fun run(action: Runnable)
}

// elsewhere...
fun consumerOfDegenerate(instance: Degenerate) {
  instance.run {
    // I want to call instance::run
    // but instead it is calling the scope function
```

IntelliJ gives the following warning message

> Candidate resolution will be changed soon, please use fully qualified name to invoke the following closer candidate explicitly:
> `public abstract fun run(action: Runnable): Unit defined in com.acme.Degenerate`

but I can't figure out the syntax to actually *do* that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what "fully qualified name" (in the context of a function name) means in the warning message, but specifying the parameter name would work:

```
instance.run(action = {
    ...
})
```

The scope function `run` has the parameter name `block`, which is different from your `run` method.

If the parameter names also happen to be the same, you can create a `Runnable` explicitly, since the scope function `run` takes a `() -> Unit` instead:

```
instance.run(Runnable {
    ...
})
```

Comment: Good idea! We have this problem in lots of places as part of a Java -> Kotlin conversion. In the long run, we'd like to convert from `Runnable` to `() -> Unit`, and then this would stop working. I guess `run` is effectively a keyword now, and you can't really use it as a method name anymore?

Comment: @NedTwigg If your method actually accepts `() -> Unit` instead, then you wouldn't have this problem. It resolves to your method by default, and won't resolve to the scope function. That's nice I guess.